# Typescript generics unlimited nested object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Trying to define a type/interface for a structure of unlimited nested objects but its value must be number|number[].

```js
type TValue = number | number[];
type TDataLevel1 = {
  [key: string]: TValue;
};
type TDataLevel2 = {
  [key: string]: TValue | TDataLevel1;
};
type TData = {
  [key: string]: TValue | TDataLevel2;
};
```

This works up to 3 levels of nested objects. However, the JSON path .key2.key2.key2.key1 has error since it is the 4th level.

```
  let data: TData = {
    key1: 1234,
    key2: {
      key1: [2, 4],
      key2: {
        key1: [6, 8],
        key2: { key1: [10, 12, 14] },  // error here
      },
    },
  };
```

This can be resolved by adding more boilerplate TDataLevel3,4..,N to support N levels. Is there any better way to define such kind of data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can simply reference the type recursively:

```
type TDataB = {
  [key: string]: TValue | TDataB;
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgagQwDYFdoF4oDsUFsBGEATlAD7Z6FEDaAugNwBQoksAIgsAgDIQBuEJAEYomAN6MoUqNQDWEEAC4oAZ2BEAllgDmtZfGRomAXyYtoMDl14CkAJlFQJ0mfKWr1W3fsSpo5S04efkEhEzNwCysER2dpOQVlNU0dPVhfNDJ2IJtBO3DGZkjsrgAhWMl4tyTPVJ9DfxKEUsZjQqQIYCgAEyD9aPLxSqk3IWUhOwBmABYAGmGoNztlOJcRhTGZO1moadp5tekllYXD9ZBN6gA2HYAOfdOz46dFjeVqIQAGHYmfvahjDsoAB6YFQYhEAD2JAAFsQII8pICFsjTIwgA)

Comment: Excellent! It works. I can now remove the boilerplate code. Thanks, ghybs!